# C# delegates from C++

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, delegates, callback

I've the followin situation: a C++ library that "talks" with a I/O device via serial port. The C++ library do some polling on the device and when an input is set a callback function is called:

```
#if defined( _MSC_VER ) || defined( __MINGW32__ ) || defined( __MINGW64__ )
#   define LIB_CALLBACK __stdcall
#   define LIB_CALL __cdecl
#   if defined( LIB_EXPORTS )
#       define LIB_API __declspec( dllexport )
#   else
#       define LIB_API __declspec( dllimport )
#   endif
#else
#   define LIB_API
#endif // WIN32

#if defined( __cplusplus )
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef int libInput;
typedef void (* LIB_CALLBACK libOnInput )  ( libInput buttons );

LIB_API void LIB_CALL libRegisterInput( libInput f );

#if defined( __cplusplus )
}
#endif
```

This is the thread function

```
libOnInput g_libOnInputFunc = nullptr;

LIB_API void LIB_CALL libRegisterInput( libInput f )
{
    libOnInputFunc = f;
}

// while true
if ( g_iocOnInputFunc )
{
    libInput = // ...
    // the event is called asyncronously. I don't want block the current thread
    std::thread t( g_libOnInputFunc, in );
    t.detach();
}
```

Now this library must be used from a VB.net application. So I've wrapped my library in C#

```
public delegate void OnInputDownDelegate(int input);

[DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void libRegisterInput( OnInputDownDelegate f );

public void RegisterOnInput(OnButtonDownDel f)
{
    libRegisterInput(f);
}
```

Now on Visual Basic I use directly the C# wrapper library:

```
Imports CSharpLib

Public Class Form1


Private Shared myLib As CSharpLib.CSharpLib

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myLib = New CSharpLib.CSharpLib()
    myLib.RegisterOnButtonDown(New CSharpLib.OnInputDownDelegate(AddressOf OnInput))
End Sub

Private Sub OnInput(ByVal input As Integer)
    MessageBox.Show(input.ToString())
End Sub

End Class
```

But when I run the application if I push a button on the device, mylib.dll catch the input and wants to call the callback function but the application crash. Seems that I'm calling a delegate on a null reference.

This is the error code:

```
Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' in Modulo sconosciuto.

Informazioni aggiuntive: Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
```

Translated is:

```
Exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' in Unknown Module

Extra information: Reference to an object not setted on an object instance
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more information - on which line does it crash? What's the error?

Comment: I've edited to provide more infomations

Comment: I'd be guessing there error your getting is trying to import libRegisterInput. Casting the delegate as a function pointer can be done (using System.InteropServices.Runtime.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate) but it is finicky. I always tend to write my wrappers in C++/CLI so I can use the delegate calls more directly, but that is just me.

Comment: I've no error when calling libRegisterInput. The error occur when the callback is called from native c++ library.

Comment: The delegate object you create is going to get garbage collected, the GC cannot see that the C++ code uses it.  You'll need to store it so the GC can always see a reference to it.  Like a Shared field of your class.  You'd better also do something to ensure that no callback can be made anymore after the form is closed.

Comment: thank you. I've resolved the problem declaring the delegate inside the wrapper C# library. Then inside RegisterOnButtonDown I assign the delegate. In this way GC doesn't delete the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to store the reference of the delegate to avoid that GC delete the reference of the delegate:

```
public delegate void OnInputDownDelegate(int input);
private OnInputDownDelegate mDelegate;

[DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void libRegisterInput( OnInputDownDelegate f );

public void RegisterOnInput(OnButtonDownDel f)
{
    mDelegate = f;
    libRegisterInput( mDelegate );
}
```